# Javascript: Full Outer Join on a Array of Objects, using one key

Tags: javascript, dataset, lodash

I have two arrays of objects which I want to "Full Outer Join", like in SQL:

Dataset A:

```
[ { id: 1, name: "apple", color: "red" }, {id: 2, name: "banana", color: "yellow"} ]
```

Dataset B:

```
[ { id: 1, name: "apple", color: "blue" }, {id: 3, name: "mango", color: "green"} ]
```

Intended result:

```
[ { id: 1, dataset_a: { id: 1, name: "apple", color: "red" }
         , dataset_b: { id: 1, name: "apple", color: "blue" }
  }
, { id: 2, dataset_a: { id: 2, name: "banana", color: "yellow"}
         , dataset_b: null
  }
, { id: 3, dataset_a: null
         , dataset_b: { id: 3, name: "mango", color: "green"}
  }
]
```

- The id's are unique.
- Lodash may be used.
- I have no restriction on ES version.

Instead of null, an empty object would be OK too. The id's don't necessarily need to be repeated, as shown below. So, this would be just as good:

```
[ { id: 1, dataset_a: { name: "apple", color: "red" }
         , dataset_b: { name: "apple", color: "blue" }
  }
, { id: 2, dataset_a: { name: "banana", color: "yellow"}
         , dataset_b: {}
  }
, { id: 3, dataset_a: {}
         , dataset_b: { name: "mango", color: "green"}
  }
]
```

Nina Scholtz solution, transformed into a a function:

```
fullOuterJoin(dataset_a_name, dataset_b_name, dataset_a, dataset_b, key) {
    const getNullProperties = keys => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, null]));
    var data = { [dataset_a_name]:dataset_a, [dataset_b_name]:dataset_b },
        result = Object
            .entries(data)
            .reduce((r, [table, rows]) => {
                //forEach dynamic destructuring
                rows.forEach(({ [key]:id, ...row }) => {
                    if (!r[id]) r.items.push(r[id] = { [key]:id, ...getNullProperties(r.tables) });
                    r[id][table] = row;
                });
                r.tables.push(table);
                r.items.forEach(item => r.tables.forEach(t => item[t] = item[t] || null));
                return r;
            }, { tables: [], items: [] })
            .items;

    return result;
},
```

Comment: And have you tried anything yourself?  Can you share the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a dynamic approach and store the wanted data sets in an object and iterate the entries form the object. Then group by `id` and get all items back.

This approach uses an object as hash table with `id` as key and an array as storage for the result set. If an `id` is not known, a new object with `id` and previously used keys with `null` value are used. Then the actual data set is added to the object.

Finally for missing tables `null` values are assigned as well.

```js
const
    getNullProperties = keys => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, null]));

var dataset_a = [{ id: 1, name: "apple", color: "red" }, { id: 2, name: "banana", color: "yellow" }],
    dataset_b = [{ id: 1, name: "apple", color: "blue" }, { id: 3, name: "mango", color: "green" }],
    data = { dataset_a, dataset_b },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .reduce((r, [table, rows]) => {
            rows.forEach(({ id, ...row }) => {
                if (!r[id]) r.items.push(r[id] = { id, ...getNullProperties(r.tables) });
                r[id][table] = row;
            });
            r.tables.push(table);
            r.items.forEach(item => r.tables.forEach(t => item[t] = item[t] || null));
            return r;
        }, { tables: [], items: [] })
        .items;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Very nice and works very well! Will have to sit down with a strong coffee to start to understand it :)

Comment: I've kinda figured out how it works. For those stumbling upon this question/answer later, to make it a dynamic function like "fullOuterJoin(dataset_a, dataset_b, key)", change the forEach "destructuring" into: rows.forEach(({ [key]:id, ...row }) => {

Answer (score 1):

A code snippet for specifically your need:

```
const datasetA = [ { id: 1, name: "apple", color: "red" }, {id: 2, name: "banana", color: "yellow"} ]
const datasetB = [ { id: 1, name: "apple", color: "blue" }, {id: 3, name: "mango", color: "green"} ]


const joined = [];

// datasetA
for (let i = 0; i < datasetA.length; i++) {
    let item = {
        id: datasetA[i].id,
        dataset_a: datasetA[i],
    };
    joined.push(item);
}
// datasetB
for (let i = 0; i < datasetB.length; i++) {
    const foundObject = joined.find(d => d.id === datasetB[i].id);
    if (foundObject) {
        foundObject['dataset_b'] = datasetB[i];
    }
    else {
        let item = {
            id: datasetB[i].id,
            dataset_a: {},
            dataset_b: datasetB[i],
        };
        joined.push(item);
    }
}

console.log(joined);
```

Comment: Works, as does Nina's approach, which has the added benefit to by dynamic. Will do a performance comparison later. Thanks for sharing, it's very educative to have a closer look at different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = [ { id: 1, name: "apple", color: "red" }, {id: 2, name: "banana", color: "yellow"} ]
var array2 = [ { id: 1, name: "apple", color: "blue" }, {id: 3, name: "mango", color: "green"} ]

var array_sum = array1.concat(array2)

var array_result = []

array_sum.forEach(function(candidate, index){
  var obj_id = candidate.id;
  delete candidate.id
  if(array_result.length == 0){
    array_result.push({
      "id": obj_id,
      ["dataset_" + index]: candidate
    })
  }else{
    for(var i=0; i<array_result.length; i++){
      if(array_result[i].id == obj_id){
        array_result[i]["dataset_" + index] = candidate
        break;
      }else if(i == array_result.length - 1){
        array_result.push({
          "id": obj_id,
          ["dataset_" + index]: candidate
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
console.log(array_result)
```